# Play (the role of) Main Character

Tags: meaning, usage

I am confused about these possibly nonstandard sentences concerning theater acting:

1. "He played ***the role of*** the main character."
2. "He played the main character."
3. "He performed ***the role of*** the main character."
4. "He performed the main character."

Dictionaries seem to equate "*role*" to "*character*".  So, are sentences 1 & 3 poorly written due to redundancies of "*the role of*"?

Comment: It should be noted: You can say something two different ways without one of them being [poorly written](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A6362+%22poorly+written%22).

Answer (score 2):

I think they are equivalent. You could say (1) is redundant but it's a common way of phrasing it nonetheless. Both sound perfectly normal and I have not been able to think of any difference in meaning.

"The role of" might be standard to say in reviews or writing about theater, but that's a guess.

(I speak American English.)

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are well constructed, and both are unambiguous if the context limits the word *he* to an actor.

Without the context, however, the shorter sentence could be a somewhat colloquial reference to another character betraying or manipulating the main character. The first sentence does not have that ambiguity.

---

[Response to request in comments about the new sentences 3 and 4.]

Sentences 3 and 4 are poorly written. One normally performs an action (e.g. perform an operation), not a role. However, you could say, "He performed *as* the main character."

Comment: I added two more sentences using the verb "perform" in place of the verb "play".  Could you offer some comment on the them?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've addressed those sentences below my main answer.